# RuntimeException: bad array lengths using Parcel

Tags: android, parcel

Would be someone able to tell me how such a simple code can throw "RuntimeException: bad array lengths" on line "in.readLongArray(longArray);", extremely rare, I was never able to reproduce it but saw it in crash reports.

```
    private long issueId;

    /**
     * compliance for Parcelable
     */
    public Download() {}

    //parcelling part
    public Download (Parcel in) {
        long[] longArray = new long[1];
        in.readLongArray(longArray);
        this.issueId = longArray[0];
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeLongArray(new long[] {this.issueId});
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Download> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Download>() {
        public Download createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Download(in);
        }
        public Download[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Download[size];
        }
    };
```

Comment: Sounds pretty unlikely without the Parcel's data becoming correupted somehow...? Alternatively, this could happen if you are trying to unparcel something that is in fact not a Download-parcel. Do you think that is possible? That exception is thrown when the in-array has a different length than the one that was written to the Parcel.

Comment: why do you use an array if you want to parcel one long?

Comment: because it is simplified example